# The button the roblox studio isn't working

Tags: lua

When I click a button isn't not working

`script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function() print("Hello world!") end)`

I tried with localscript and script and not working. What do I do? And when I click in the button the GUI vanish.